# How to exclude migration folder from code coverage analyze result by runsettings file?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

I want exclude all migration classes from the code coverage analyze result. So I used the following code in `codecoverage.runsettings` file but code coverage analyze result is include migration namespace classes yet.

The namespace of migration classes is `MySolution.Data.Migrations` and they are in the `Migrations` directory of the `MySolution.Data` project.

Data Project > `codecoverage.runsettings`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>
        <DataCollectors>
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
                <Configuration>
                    <CodeCoverage>
                          <!-- configuration elements -->
                          <Functions>
                              <Exclude>
                                  <Function>.*\.Data.Migrations\..**</Function>
                              </Exclude>
                          </Functions>
                    </CodeCoverage>
                </Configuration>
            </DataCollector>
        </DataCollectors>
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the following code:

```
<!-- Exclude Migrations folder -->
<Exclude>
   <Function>^MySolution.Data\.Migrations\..*</Function>
</Exclude>
```